# Upload file to FTP server without read permissions

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest, ftpwebresponse

I want to upload and store some of my backups to another server via an FTP account.
This account has only read permissions (no write permissions), to prevent attackers from deleting my backups.

So I started to code the solution with full permissions (aka read + write). This how my code looks: (this code is currently working)

```
        string file = @"C:\1.html";
        FtpWebRequest ftpClient = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FTPUrl"]) + @"/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));
        ftpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpUserName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FtpPassword"]);
        ftpClient.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
        ftpClient.UseBinary = true;
        ftpClient.KeepAlive = true;
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
        ftpClient.ContentLength = fi.Length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
        int bytes = 0;
        int total_bytes = (int)fi.Length;
        System.IO.FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();
        System.IO.Stream rs = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();
        while (total_bytes > 0)
        {
            bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
            total_bytes = total_bytes - bytes;
        }
        fs.Close();
        rs.Close();
```

But, when I remove the read permissions, it no longer works. 
The problematic code line is:

```
    System.IO.Stream rs = ftpClient.GetRequestStream();
```

And the error is:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (550)
>   File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).

Theoretically, it seems okay to upload a file without read permissions (also works with FileZilla). Practically, it's not working for me. Can someone give me a solution for this case?

Comment: It seems to me that you're getting the requeststream which is used for reading. When you attempt to read and you don't have read permissions, it will think that the file doesn't exist. Now if you try to write it should work

Comment: At the start of your question you said you had no write permission.  Did you get read and write mixed up?

Comment: No, we started develop the code without read\write limitation. After this worked, we removed the read permission.